# Android JNI C++ segmentation fault

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I wrote the following native function for extracting the coordinates of the white pixels of a binary `Mat`:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_testapp_MainActivity_findCornersJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, cv::Mat In, cv::Mat Out){
    int Number_Of_Elements;
    Mat Binary_Image;
    cvtColor(In, Binary_Image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat NonZero_Locations = cv::Mat::zeros(Binary_Image.size(),Binary_Image.channels());
    if (Binary_Image.empty())
        std::cout << "Input is empty!" << std::endl;
        return;

    findNonZero(Binary_Image, NonZero_Locations);
    //cout << "Non-Zero Locations = " << NonZero_Locations << endl << endl;

    Number_Of_Elements = NonZero_Locations.total();
    //cout << "Total Number Of Array Elements = " << Number_Of_Elements << endl << endl;

    NonZero_Locations.copyTo(Out);
    delete &NonZero_Locations;
    return;
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault error at runtime:

```
libc Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x00000000 (code=128), thread 7914
```

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Does `delete &NonZero_Locations;` *look* like a good idea to you?

Comment: In case Kerrek SB's sarcasm wasn't clear enough; It's not a good idea. Just. Don't. If you want to release it, you must use NonZero_Locations.release();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information this is only a wild guess, but:
According to the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-zeros), you use `Mat::zeros` to create a Mat object on the stack:

```
Mat NonZero_Locations = cv::Mat::zeros(Binary_Image.size(),Binary_Image.channels());
```

Later, you delete the local stack object.

```
delete &NonZero_Locations;
```

Generally, in C++, you only delete dynamically allocated objects. Stack objects are destroyed when leaving their scope. So, in your case you do not have to (and you're not allowed to) delete `NonZero_Locations`.

Comment: What a rookie mistake (after hours and hours of programming my brain does not work well) Great answer, thanks!

Comment: I know this feeling. You always look over it and think "Oh, its just a delete, what could possibly go wrong".